# Method Laravel\Passport\Bridge\AccessToken::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught InvalidArgumentException error after upgrading

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-8

I'm getting error mentioned above after upgrading to laravel 8 and laravel/passport 10.x. Did anyone face the problem?

```
Actual stacktrace: Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError: Method Laravel\Passport\Bridge\AccessToken::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught InvalidArgumentException: It was not possible to parse your key, reason: error:09091064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio_ex:bad base64 decode in file /Users/<path>/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/ResponseTypes/BearerTokenResponse.php on line 0
```

I tried creating user and login in and It is working ie creating record in db, It just the problem while sending response.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Actual stacktrace: Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError: Method Laravel\Passport\Bridge\AccessToken::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught InvalidArgumentException: It was not possible to parse your key, reason: error:09091064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio_ex:bad base64 decode in file /Users/<path>l/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/ResponseTypes/BearerTokenResponse.php on line 0

I tried creating user and login in. It is working ie creating recrod in db, It just the problem while sending response in my opinion

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

I was facing such a problem after running `composer update` where the third-party package `lcobucci/jwt` was updated. It was fixed after downgrading the version of `lcobucci/jw` to **3.3.3** by the following command:

```
composer require lcobucci/jwt 3.3.3
```